# Update Joomla website

Tags: joomla, web, updates

I updated my Joomla website on localhost - just the content of some Articles. Do I need to upload all the joomla folders to remote server to see these updates on the webpage? Is it possible just to upload some specific folders with articles (where this folder is located inside the Joomla directory)?

Answer (score 1):

Seems, that you are some kind of new to this topic. So if you just updates '*some*' articles, than I would really not mess around with the database. You may also edit the articles on the live side and do some copy & paste. That should be the safer way.

Answer (score 0):

Articles and all other data is stored in a database which can be retrieved from phpmyadmin. Simply export the database and import it to the phpmyadmin on your online server